# Yeshivas that have closed

Tags: yeshiva-school, history, chinuch-education

Recently there was a blog regarding the Shlomo Kluger Yeshiva on the Lower East Side. My father was a student at Yeshiva Eitz Chaim in Boro Park in the the early 40s. Over the years many Yeshivas or girl schools have closed and I am sure many of them have alumni with fond memories.

Can we please get names and locations of Yeshivas and Bais Yaakovs that are no longer open?

Comment: Gershon, I don't really see a clear question here. Could you please rephrase so there is one?

Comment: Names, places and memories of Yeshivas and Bais Yaakovs that are no longer open.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear what you're asking. Please note that asking for a list of closed Yeshivas is closer to being an answerable information request than asking for memories. Asking in general for memories is more discussion-oriented and not exactly consistent with the Q&A format of this site. On the other hand, asking specific questions that people can answer from their experience (e.g. Did students at Yeshivas XYZ in the '30s get adequate food?) is a great use of the site.

Comment: Are we only referring to yeshivot post WWII?

Comment: Shem and Ever..

Comment: @AdamMosheh, it seems so, as the pre-WWII list would be exhaustive.

Comment: @YDK - So what if it is exhaustive?  Look at this meta thread: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/959/what-is-our-attitude-to-list-questions

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, actually, I don't know where I heard this idea (but it doesn't stick in my head as having been from an authoritative source), but I've heard that that _y'shiva_ never closed: rather it split into all the _y'shivos_ since.

Comment: Does anyone know info on the yeshiva of the South in Memphis ran by Rav belsKY ( not related to torah vdaas)?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're referring to post-World War Two yeshivos? Most others are gone (though some, like the Mir, remain, most of them displaced). If you include them, you've got quite a list: ones that come immediately to mind were in Bavel (Sura, Pumbedisa, ...), pre-Nazi continental Europe, and [pre-First-Crusade Rhineland (Mainz, Speyer, Worms, ...)](http://web.archive.org/web/20071009143243/www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/crusade/index.html).

As far as post-World War Two goes, there [was a yeshiva g'dola here in St. Louis, Mo.](http://www.shemayisrael.com/ravaharon/rgreen.htm), which has closed. (It was for a time in [Eureka, Mo.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka,_MO))

Comment: Re WWII, see also [Adam Mosheh's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15350).

Answer (score 5):

In the 50's, Rav Simcha Wasserman established Ohr Elchonon high schoolin Los Angeles.  It was located on Kings Road and Willoughby.  The yeshiva closed in the 70's when Rav Simcha made aliya.  Rav Simcha wished that the building always remain a yeshiva and named after his father.  Chabad agreed to this stipulation and bought the yeshiva and its surrounding few acres.  Chabad used the campus for a few years, naming the yeshiva Ohr Elchonon Chabad.  The building was eventually transported to a different part of town (near Hancock park). (Rav Simcha expressed disappointment about that).  The old grounds were sold for condos.

Comment: You don't need to justify the strict meaning of the words.  Others have already done that.  But that was not the intent of Rav Simcha.

Comment: can you please cite sources?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, Sources that the Yeshiva existed- I know at least 3 people who attended the yeshiva.  It's location- I was personally in the building as a child, my grandparents lived only a few blocks away.  The stipulations and R' Simcha's expression came from a friend who had access to this information.  Although that the stipulations existed can be inferred from the facts- why else would Chabad move a building that they have no historical attachment to and name their yeshiva after someone they had no historical relationship with?

Comment: @YDK - Because you're just somebody random on the Internet?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, whether Chabad is a new entity or the same- I don't know.  Why did R' Simcha care?  Because he toiled to create a yeshiva kedosha there. Perhaps if the area went bad, he wouldn't care as much.  But the circumstances surrounding the move may have looked to R' Simcha like the Chabad yeshiva wanted to be in a more up-and-coming area to begin with and bought the campus (at a discount I am told) in order to flip it for condos.  Should he care might have a different answer than did he care.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, you are correct.  You should not act based on any of my information without consulting with your rav.

Comment: @YDK - Other than the fact that this is history and not halakhah, I agree with you.  I don't have anything against you personally, so I apologize if you took it that way.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, sorry I was a little curt in my retort.  I thought your first comment for sources was appropriate since my answer was merely a monologue.  After clarifying my 1st/2nd hand knowledge of, like you said, a recent historical event, I thought your 2nd comment was scratching where it didn't itch.

Answer (score 3):

The first real Lithuanian  *mussar* style Yeshivah in America was started by HaGaon Rav Yehudah Levenberg and HaGaon Rav Sheftel Kramer in New Haven in the 20's.

Eventually it moved to Cleveland along with Rav Levenberg's new Rabbanus position and became known as "*Yeshivah D'New Haven, Ka'ays B'Cleveland*". During this period Rav Ruderman (Rav Sheftel's son-in-law) joined the Yeshivah.

When Rav Levenberg's new position did not work out and he was offered his old position back he wanted to move the Yeshivah back to New Haven. Rav Sheftel felt that this would be detrimental to the Yeshivah and the first Mahlokes in a Yeshivah in America was born!
Rav Leizer Silver sat as the Av Beis Din and the decision was reached to split the Yeshivah.

Rav Sheftel continued with Rav Ruderman and half of the original Talmidim. While on a fundraising trip to Baltimore, Rav Ruderman was offered to start a Yeshivah there. He asked Rav Sheftel permission and Rav Sheftel gave him some of his top students. That is how Yeshivas Ner Yisrael was born. The New Haven Yeshivah Ka'ays B'Cleveland did not last much longer.

I just heard another postscript to this saga:

Some time after the *Din Torah*, one day when Rav Sheftel was learning in the empty Beis HaMedrash, a young man walked in. Rav Sheftel gave him sholom and asked him his name. He replied "Moshe Feinstein". (!) Rav Sheftel asked him what he was doing in Cleveland and he replied that he had accepted the position of Rosh HaYeshiva in that Yeshivah. Without saying anything about his position and authority in the Yeshivah, Rav Sheftel picked himself up, took his *seforim* and left the building. When Rav Moshe found out that he had been used as a pawn in a low-down trick, he left and went on to become the *Rosh HaYeshivah* of MTJ.

Comment: So- Yeshiva d'New Haven d'Nechlaka b'Cleveland u'k'Ays b'New Haven?

Comment: No. Absolutely not. Rav Levenberg never actually moved back. Like all Mahlokisim there is more than meets the eye but not really in the public's interest to be discussed. The current Yeshivah in New Haven was founded by Rabbi Greer.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a Yeshiva in Seattle, Washington (in the 70's). ([See](http://www.chabadsa.com/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/66288/jewish/About-Us.htm) the section about Rabbi Block).

Answer (score 1):

There used to be an elementry school in Brooklyn known as Ohel Yaakov. It closed in the 70s and was affiliated with Novordok.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volozhin_yeshiva), Yeshivat Volozhin has not been operating since around 1939.

Comment: See [my answer, above](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2944).

Comment: I saw your answer and I was also mesupak regarding what the asker of this question wants to know.  So I answered the question.  Anything wrong with that?

Comment: No, I was just linking to a related post.